# Adding a read more arrow inside a nav menu dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a navigation menu that opens up on hover. One of the nav items is going to be fairly long and I don't want it to cover up most of the page so I was looking for something that would act as a secondary nav inside the dropdown menu.

Here is a rough mock of what I was picturing:

[image: Here is a rough mock of what I was picturing.]

And my code right now looks like this:

```js
//----------------------------------------------
//script that lets you hover over drop down menus, but only on desktop.
//----------------------------------------------


initializeHover();

$(window).resize(initializeHover);

function initializeHover() {
    $('ul.nav > li.dropdown').unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');
    $('ul.nav > li.dropdown > .dropdown-menu').css('display', '');

    if ($(window).width() >= 992) {
        $('ul.nav > li.dropdown').hover(function () {
            $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(90).slideDown(200);
        }, function () {
            $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(90).slideUp(200);
        });
    }
}
```

```css
.navbar.navbar-ot {
  background-color: #2db2e9;
  padding: 5px 50px;
  position: fixed;
}
.navbar.navbar-ot .navbar-brand {
  padding-top: 20px;
}
.navbar.navbar-ot ul li a {
  padding: 30px 10px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 13px;
}
.navbar.navbar-ot ul li a:hover {
  background-color: inherit;
}
.navbar.navbar-ot .dropdown-menu {
  top: 107%;
  border: none;
}
.navbar.navbar-ot .dropdown-menu li a {
  padding: 15px 40px;
  color: #2db2e9;
}
.navbar.navbar-ot .dropdown-menu li a:hover {
  color: #1698cd;
  background-color: #eee;
}
.navbar.navbar-ot .navbar-right {
  padding-top: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.navbar.navbar-ot .navbar-right .btn {
  font-weight: 600 !important;
}
.navbar.navbar-ot .navbar-right .btn.btn-outline {
  border: 2px solid #fff !important;
  color: #fff !important;
}
.navbar.navbar-ot .navbar-right .btn.btn-white {
  color: #2db2e9;
}
.navbar.navbar-ot.navbar-ot-white {
  background-color: #fff;
}
.navbar.navbar-ot.navbar-ot-white ul li.active > a {
  font-weight: 800;
  color: #1387b6;
}
.navbar.navbar-ot.navbar-ot-white ul li a {
  color: #2db2e9;
}
.navbar.navbar-ot.navbar-ot-white ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
.navbar.navbar-ot.navbar-ot-white .navbar-right .btn.btn-outline {
  border: 2px solid #2db2e9 !important;
  color: #2db2e9 !important;
  -webkit-transition: background-color ease 0.3s;
  -o-transition: background-color ease 0.3s;
  transition: background-color ease 0.3s;
}
.navbar.navbar-ot.navbar-ot-white .navbar-right .btn.btn-outline:hover {
  color: #fff !important;
  background-color: #2db2e9;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<header>
  <nav class="nav navbar-nav navbar navbar-ot navbar-ot-white navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#ot-nav">
                        <i class="fa fa-navicon text-white"></i>
                    </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="ot-nav">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Features <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Feature</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Feature</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Feature</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Feature</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-alt" data-no-scroll="">Book a Demo</a> &nbsp; &nbsp;
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-outline btn-alt">Log In</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
  </nav>
</header>
```

I know how to use a "Read More" type of button, but I was hoping that rather than just expanding the drop down, it would scroll the content to reveal more and add another arrow to the top to navigate back up the list. So that only, say 5 items are showing at any given time in the drop down. Does anyone know how to achieve this? If so, would it also work on mobile? I'm new with JavaScript and I'm assuming it's going to require a bit of script.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom CSS class such as `scroll-menu`:

```
.scroll-menu {
    height: auto;
    max-height: 150px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

After that, you can simply add that class to the `<ul>` sub-menu in the bootstrap navbar:

```
    <ul class="dropdown-menu scroll-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Feature</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Feature</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Feature</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Feature</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Here is a [simple codepen](https://codepen.io/prahladyeri/pen/eKPGVg) using your own example. This creates a very basic scrolling for the menus, of course. For up/down arrow style scrolling, you need to make use of CSS animations/transitions.

[image]

Comment: While this is a solution to the problem, it's not the solution I'm looking for.